# How can I set PermitTunnel in sshd_config?

Tags: ssh

After setting "PermitTunnel = yes" in /etc/ssh/sshd_config, sshd does not start anymore:
Bad configuration option: PermitTunnel

CentOS 5.5 64 Bit, openssh-server version 4.3p2, release 41.el5_5.1

Works on another server with same configuration.

Answer (score 4):

Actually sshd_config's options are set w/o '='.

```
$ grep PermitTunnel  /etc/ssh/sshd_config
#PermitTunnel no
```

Comment: I just wrote the = in here to clarify what I would like to set.

Comment: Have you succeeded in clarification? :)